# how to select a table column on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there away to select a table column on a condition ?, in this query :

```
SELECT x,y FROM Z
```

I want to make selecting the y column Y is conditioned, as:

```
SELECT x ( ONLY WHERE x_type = '20' ), y FROM Z # just example of what i am trying to do :)
```

y_type is another column, it's value is what on which selecting Y or not depends !, Is there away to do that, or i am just hitting the wrong door ?

Comment: And for those rows that `x_type` is not `20`, what will be shown in column `y` ?

Comment: I dont think your explanation is that clear on what you want to do.

Comment: return Null, if it's necessary

Comment: My expression is just assuming the possible way to do it ... i don't know .. i am just explaining my idea ... select a column depending on another's value ... did that help in any way ?

Comment: What you want is possible, but highly unusual. You are probably wanting this for the wrong reason.

Comment: let me explain more, and you tell me ...
the column Y (LongText) is open for any type of value .. text, long text, html ... just anything .. so sometimes it's very big in size to call it in a grid for example .. so i am trying to check for it's value type ( that is saved in y_type ) if it was 20 ( for example ) then it's ok to select it, else ( big size data ) dont !

Did that help in anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN y_type = 20 THEN y ELSE NULL END As y -- replace y_type with column to check
,.... -- other column list
FROM yourtable
```

You can also use a CASE with IN for multiple values eg.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN y_type IN (10,20) THEN y ELSE NULL END As y -- replace y_type with column to check
,.... -- other column list
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You could set the column to NULL if the condition is not met, though:

```
SELECT    IF (x_type = 20, x, NULL) AS x
          y
FROM      Z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when x_type = '20' then
x else '' end,y from z
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the details:

```
SELECT x
     , CASE WHEN x_type = '20' THEN y
                               ELSE NULL
       END AS y
FROM Z
```

or perhaps you want the simple:

```
SELECT x
     , y
FROM Z
WHERE x_type = '20'
```

Comment: Thanks, ... the " simple " one, wouldn't return with the whole record !, i am just trying to control the selected columns ... Y sometimes is Big in size, so , i don't wanna call it when it's type = 20 or some !, got me ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select on x_type, then your SQL query should be

```
SELECT x, y FROM Z where x_type = '20'
```

If you'd like to constrain on y_type, then you might want to add `OR y_type = 'nn'` to the end. I think your question is whether or not you need to have the same column in both the select clause and in the where clause. The answer is "no, you don't have to."